# How to match regular expression but return the remaining part of the input in Rust Nom?

Tags: regex, rust, nom

I am trying to use Nom 6.1.2 to parse a relatively simple Lisp like language, where I need to capture identifiers of the form `[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]`. I tried to use `re_match` but this is expecting the whole `input` to match not just the first part of the string. I want to be able to match these identifiers as part of a larger context, so I want it to return the remaining part of the input to be passed on to other parsers, in a parser combinator fashion.

```
fn name(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str, VerboseError<&str>> {
    let re = Regex::new(r"^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*$").unwrap();
    context("name", re_match(re))(input)
}
```

The test I want this to pass is the following:

```
#[test]
fn test_name() {
    assert_eq!(name("test"), Ok(("", "test")));
    assert_eq!(name("test1-test2"), Ok(("", "test1-test2")));
    assert_eq!(name("test1.test2"), Ok(("", "test1.test2")));
    assert_eq!(name("test1_test2"), Ok(("", "test1_test2")));
    assert_eq!(name("Test1_Test2"), Ok(("", "Test1_Test2")));
    assert!(name("123Test").is_err());

    //this last assertion fails
    assert_eq!(name("test1 test2$!%"), Ok((" test2$!%", "test1")));
}
```

The last assertion in the above test fails.

```
thread 'parser::tests::test_name' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Err(Error(VerboseError { errors: [("test1 test2$!%", Nom(RegexpMatch)), ("test1 test2$!%", Context("name"))] }))`,
 right: `Ok((" test2$!%", "test1"))`', src\parser.rs:69:9
stack backtrace:
```

If I was using something like the `alphanumeric` function this would work fine, but this doesn't capture the regular expression I want.

I could hand code this myself and somehow check the first character and the subsequent ones, but I have several other situations where I need to parse different regular expressions, and it will become unmaintainable.

What is the right way to take the part that matches a regular expression and continue with parsing the rest of the larger input?

Comment: use regex while using nom defeat all logics

Comment: @Stargateur what logics are you talking about? regex is perfectly fine to use to match identifiers and similar things in parser combinators. Even parser combinators in Scala work with regex seamlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this out and part of the problem is with the $ at the end of the regex.  That will tell the regex matcher to match the whole input up until the end, or else there will be no match.

The other issue is with re_match().  From the nom docs, re_match will return the whole input if a match is found (regardless of how many characters matched).  What you want is the re_find() function, which will return the first match.

Comment: Without the `$` at the end it will keep matching the rest of the input including non-matching characters after the whitespace which don't have anything to do with the identifier. The assertion will still fail because I will get `Ok(("", "test1 test2$!%"))` instead of `Ok((" test2$!%", "test1"))`.

Comment: Sorry, you need to remove the $ *and* also use the re_find() functions instead of the re_match() function.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: Great, I didn't realise I could use `re_find` with the `^` to force it to match the start of the string.